# vb.net: lower level debugging

Tags: vb.net

i know how to do basic debugging. is it possible to do lower level debugging in vb.net? i would like to see more detail on what's happening on a lower level

Comment: Can you give us some information on what you'd like to see?

Comment: i would like to see whats happening when the compiler compares whether two strings are equal

Comment: I'd advise you to read the documentation. Sounds like you might be interested in case-sensitivity and the effects of cultures in string comparison? Check out *How Culture Affects Strings in Visual Basic* on MSDN here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235309.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the full version of Visual Studio 2008 (not Express), you can peek at the .Net Framework source code by following the steps outlined here: http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Since you're using Express, you'll probably need to rely on methods outside of Visual Studio (i.e. there's no way that I'm aware of to "step into" Framework code from there).

If you just want to see what's happening under the hood, you could use ildasm to disassemble your program (after compilation) and see what's happening. The steps for that are included here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceats605%28VS.80%29.aspx